# Retrieve Hard drive info through WMI .NET C#

Tags: c#, .net, wmi

So i've used this code to get S.M.A.R.T. hard drive diagnostics info from Windows WMI:

http://vasters.com/archive/Reading-ATAPI-SMART-Data-From-Drives-Using-NET-Temperature-Anyone.html

It works on most computers and doesn't on others. After a little bit research and sample testing i found out that it doesn't work on computers whose Hard drives are connected with PCI Express instead of SATA.

```
var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\WMI", "SELECT * FROM MSStorageDriver_ATAPISmartData");
    foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
    {
          //do stuff
    }
```

This is where i get exception:

System.Management.ManagementException: 'Not supported'

Is there any other way to do this, or add something in this code to make it work?

Comment: Have you read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wmisdk/wmi-tasks--disks-and-file-systems

Comment: in addition to @BugFinder I'd like to add that there's a much cleaner way of getting this info now via System.IO.DriveInfo.GetDrives()

Comment: You can try to create C# wrapper for unmanaged code https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/fileio/working-with-nvme-devices#example-nvme-get-log-pages-query, also you can check source codes of some apps on GitHub https://github.com/mirror/smartmontools/blob/master/os_win32.cpp.

Comment: @BugFinder System.IO.DriveInfo.GetDrives() only gives basic information. I'm looking for S.M.A.R.T. attributes

Comment: @TomasPangonis you can use next way as temporary workaround (but check about its **LICENSE** first to be sure this way is legal): you can install smartmontools app (github link I mentioned in previous comment) and copy\use its binaries in your app. You can get SMART info about all drives using its CLI: smartctl.exe -a /dev/sda running it via Process.Start, etc and getting output.

Comment: Think I'm gonna go with wrapping unmanaged code option. This binary copying into the app sounds complicated. Thought there's a way to do it in C# but seems like everybody is doing it in C++ only.

Answer (score 1):

I searched this code everywhere and couldn't find working for me, but finaly found on another forum so it's really simple in usage.
Just from my example another way to get WMI info. More Attributes of WMI Win32_DiskDrive you can find in Microsoft DOCs
https://github.com/Mityugin/greentest

```
string NamespacePath = "\\\\.\\ROOT\\cimv2";
string ClassName = "Win32_DiskDrive";
oClass = new ManagementClass(NamespacePath + ":" + ClassName);
            foreach (ManagementObject oObject in oClass.GetInstances())
            {
                var sign = Convert.ToString(oObject["Signature"]);
                var model = Convert.ToString(oObject["Model"]);
                var status = Convert.ToString(oObject["Status"]);

                if (Equals(sign,""))
                {
                    TextBox1.AppendText("DISK model: " + model);
                    TextBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
                    TextBox1.AppendText("Status: " + status);
                    TextBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);

                    if (!status.Equals("OK") || !model.Contains("SSD"))
                    {
                        //Here is info if Disk is not OK or model not SSD
                    }
                }


            }
```

Answer (score 0):

This github solution is fine for detecting an SSD but will not tell you it is PCIE or NVMe. I have an SSD that is an older Samsung 960 series and it is an SSD connected via SATA.

The code you need to read an NVMe drive Temperature is on this website at [How do I enumerate NVMe (M2) drives an get their temperature in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55132739/how-do-i-enumerate-nvme-m2-drives-an-get-their-temperature-in-c/74916885#74916885)